# How to build subtree with Python, BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to use BeautifulSoup to compose a webpage.

When I go to set a tag's inner content via `string` it automatically escapes the string. I have yet to locate a technique, like a `html` method/attribute, where BS won't auto escape everything.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open("template.html", "r")
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'html.parser')
f.close()

x = soup.find("div", id="example")
x.string("<div>example</div>")

# x's contents...
# <div id="example">&lt;div&gt;example&lt;/div&gt;</div>
```

It's apparent that BS is more often used for scraping HTML than building HTML – is there a common library for building out?

Comment: Check this https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/). Then you can render templates like this:

```py
from jinja2 import Template

t = Template('<div id="example">{{example_div}}</div>')
t.render(example_div='<div>example</div>')
```

Resulting in:

```py
'<div id="example"><div>example</div></div>'
```

Of course, you can also read the template from a file:

```py
with open('template.html', 'r') as f:
    t = Template(f.read())
```

Comment: Ahh of course. I've used Jinja a bunch – but didn't think of it outside of the Flask context.